# Get latest months value based on date slicer in power bi measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to use a Card visual in Power BI that shows the latest's month value, called Index.
Index is a measure that subtracts two measures from each other, Ticket Creation Count - Ticket Resolved Count. Like so, `Index = [Total Ticket Count (Creation Date)] - [Total Ticket Count (Resolution Date)]`

I have tried a few different ways to get this done. `Latest Index = SUMX(DATESINPERIOD('Date Data'[Date],LASTDATE('Date Data'[Date]),-1,MONTH), [Index])`. However its giving me the sum of Index values from today to one month ago.

I just want it for the latest month (only) based on the date slicer.

Can someone help?

Thanks!